# I've downloaded VS2013 Express for Desktop Update 2, but don't see how to create a TypeScript project. What else do I need?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I thought VS2013 Express for Desktop Update 2 had everything to start a TypeScript project. Do I need anythhing else? My OS is Win8.1.

I forgot to mention that the VS2013 edition is the Express one.

Comment: There's no web project installed in my VS2013 for Desktop (just VC++, VC# and VB). I checked online templates, and there's only templates for VC# and VB - none for web. Interestingly, the compiler tsc.exe is installed and functional.

Comment: Are you using VS Express? In that case you just need the web version I bet.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it has nothing to do with the express version. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the (Web Edition of VS)[http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-web], not the Desktop Edition. Using Express is no problem.

Additionally you have to install [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42666).

After that you can create new TypeScript projects.

Comment: Thanks, well explained.

Answer (score 1):

You need the vs 2013 express web edition, that is a different install